# Combined profile page (linked from combined profile flair)

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page, hyperlinks, flair

Now that I've got a [Combined Profile Flair](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/flair), I notice that it just links to StackExchange.com. I could link it to my StackOverflow profile, but it'd be nice if StackExchange had a simple profile page for me - maybe one that just showed a list of my badges from the other sites.

Comment: Combined Profile Badge? Could you clarify what you mean?

Comment: Alternative:  If you use [StackFlair](http://stackapps.com/q/1567/2286) you can use the html version which has a link to the user profile on each favicon.

Comment: @Grace, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/flair

Comment: @rchern Oh, flair, I see... oh good heavens why is there a hot dog stand version? In any case, I'll tidy up the tags here, then.

Comment: Glad to see I'm not the only one to see this as an omission. It seem weird to link to the generic SX homepage from a badge that shows my personal stats.

Comment: I think it would be nice if all the profile pages could be linked to one Stack Exchange profile too, so I only had to fill out things one place.

Comment: ++ on this one.  Using the combined flair seems kind of pointless at the moment if your intention is to allow people to click through to your profile.

Answer (score 2):

Amongst the other flair alternatives there is [SOREPV2](https://stackapps.com/questions/1578/sorep-v2-ranked-flair-take-2) which provides an aggregate flair with links to respective profiles.

Here is an example of [your combined and ranked flair](http://stackusers.com/Users/flair/eb364efb-b033-4063-a1ef-b3fcde338935?mode=tiny&count=0), sorep style, with links to your profiles.

I am considering adding image output but this would eliminate ability to link out to profiles.

In any case, just another option.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Completed per

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/stack-exchange-network-profiles/