# StackExchange Combined Flair link

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

When you create a Combined Flair the button by default links to stackexchange.com (for a single site button it links to the profile), this is a confusing specially when you add it to your personal site, because it links to nothing related to the user (I changed mine to point to tye StackOverflow instead).

Ideally it should link to an aggregate vision of all profiles (a.k.a. [global profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65998/global-profile-for-se))

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65560/combined-profile-page-linked-from-combined-profile-flair

Answer (score 5):

This (a combined "greatest hits" / "best of" profile) is something that is planned on http://stackexchange.com